# Submitting list of items with removed first one deletes all items

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, defaultmodelbinder

i have a model that has a list of sub items in it , something like this :

```
class MyObj {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<mySubObject> Items {get;set;} 
}
```

and

```
class mySubObject { 
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Order {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when i render the list with a for loop and editorFor, the html i get is somethign like this :

```
<input type="text" name="Items[0].Name">
<input type="Number" name="Items[0].Order">
<input type="text" name="Items[1].Name">
<input type="number" name="Items[1].Order">
...
<input type="text" name="Items[9].Name">
<input type="number" name="Items[9].Order">
```

Now imagine remove the first element from the HTML via jQuery because i no longer want it in my list, and then save the list. The data that goes back is without the first `[0]` element
and all the elements from 1 to 9 go to the server but the model binding fails and it displays (on the server) that the list of items is `null`

What am i doing wrong ?

Is this a bug of the default model binder ?

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong ?

Leaving holes in the indices.

> Is this a bug of the default model binder ?

No, it's by design. You shouldn't leave any holes in the indices.

One possibility is to recalculate the indices when you remove a row but you will have to write a ton of crap javascript for that.

I would recommend you using a different approach. Instead of using sequential indices use Guids. The approach is detailed in the following blog post by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx (Non-Sequential indices section).

And Steven Sanderson illustrated a nice little helper in this post that would allow you to very easily achieve this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

That you could use like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items")) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Order)
    }
}
```

and it will generate the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Items.Index" value="F769E33C-4D07-4586-8D9C-63D386C641FA" />
<input type="text" name="Items[F769E33C-4D07-4586-8D9C-63D386C641FA].Name">
<input type="Number" name="Items[F769E33C-4D07-4586-8D9C-63D386C641FA].Order">

<input type="hidden" name="Items.Index" value="F4A4A9BB-4427-497E-BFD5-3CDE1F46095B" />
<input type="text" name="Items[F4A4A9BB-4427-497E-BFD5-3CDE1F46095B].Name">
<input type="number" name="Items[F4A4A9BB-4427-497E-BFD5-3CDE1F46095B].Order">

...
```

Now feel free to add/remove rows as much as you like on the client with javascript without fearing that it would break the model binding of your collection.

Comment: because it's that much easier to use a helper function and extra logic than to just for the default model binder to ignore indexes ? eh ? Am i the only thinks this approach is wrong .. okay maybe not wrong but less than ideal solution ?

Comment: Erm, sorry, which approach is wrong? I didn't quite understand what you mean. The fact that the default model binder ignores holes in the indices or my recommended solution with no-sequential indices? In both cases, if you don't like those approaches, as explained in my answer, you always have the possibility to recalculate the indices when you remove rows on the client. It's just an alternative method.

Comment: the fact that the default model binder ignores holes seems wrong to me. The recommended solution would work , and it's OK. But the fact that we have to write it ... :/
The other option would be to serialize to JSON and post that ...

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Quite true. Could have worked with holes. But it doesn't :-)